# jQuery date/time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

I've been looking around for a decent jQuery plugin that can handle both dates and times.  The core UI `DatePicker` is great, but unfortunately I need to be able to take time in as well.

I've found a few hacks for the DatePicker to work with times, but they all seem pretty inelegant and Google isn't turning up anything nice.

Is there a good jQuery plugin for selecting dates and times in a single UI control with a usable interface?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my example is a bit less confusing and more user friendly. There are pros and cons of both.

Comment: http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/

Answer (score 251):

By far the nicest and simplest DateTime picker option is http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/.

It is an extension of the jQuery UI Datepicker so it will support the same themes as well it works very much the same way, similar syntax, etc. This should be packaged with the jQuery UI imo.

Comment: I've been using this one, and I LOVE it.

Comment: I like this, but it's still VERY buggy.

Comment: "VERY buggy"?  Hardly.  I use it in production code, and have for a while now.  It's also actively developed.

Comment: how about setting showTime=false ? Does this support this feature ?

Comment: Not so great for mobile web apps though

Comment: @Sonny: whether you use it in production has no bearing on whether it is buggy or not.  You may just not have seen its bugs because you're not doing the things with it that expose them, which perhaps Alastair is.  On the other hand, he didn't offer any evidence for his claim, so I'm not inclined to take it too seriously...

Comment: My biggest problem with this plugin is the UI: why would I want to use sliders, horizontal ones at that!, to input a time!? It looks and feels very awkward to me.  I've had the experience so many times with sliders where I can't get it to the number that I want (repeatedly going a little over then a little under) and I end up typing it.  A keyboard is normally the easiest way to enter a precise numerical value.  If you want a visual input method, a clock is the normal one for time, not a slider.  Harder to implement, but might actually be useful (as long as keyboard input is also possible).

Comment: @sakhunzai: Why would it have a showTime=false setting?  If you don't want to use a time input, then just use the jQuery DatePicker which is packaged with jQuery UI.  This is an addon for the explicit purpose of allowing time input.

Comment: @iconoclast: If you implement it on a text-field input, as the author does in his examples, then you have the choice to type the time into the text box, and the component will even adjust to reflect the entered time after it is typed.

Comment: @Batkins: yes, but why sliders?  Using a calender offers many advantages for picking dates, and once you're using a visual input it makes sense to use another visual input for time.  But sliders are not logical in my opinion.  A better option would be breaking out HH and MM into separate fields and using up and down arrows beside or above and below the fields.  When the datetime picker widget closed, all of the data that was entered would be combined into the single regular form field.

Comment: this plugin is horribly buggy, can't even get it to work!

Comment: A few notes on the default Trent DTP page - you need to reference the jquery UI library(js/css) before the timepicker addon library.  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: And you cant even copy paste the time part. It copies only date.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts, you are right, this code needs cleanup... having bugs...

Comment: Sliders not working on android galaxy s3.

Comment: Been trying for half a day to get this thing to work, to no avail.

Answer (score 46):

@David, thanks for the recommendation!  @fluid_chelsea, I've just released Any+Time(TM) version 3.x which uses jQuery instead of Prototype and has a much-improved interface, so I hope it now meets your needs:

http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

Any problems, please let me know via the comment link on my website!

Comment: Any+Time(TM) version 4.x is now available!  The new release supports TIME ZONES (find THAT in any other picker!) as well as jQuery selectors/chaining, easy-removal (avoid memory leaks!) and many other improvements.  Please give it a ride, and if you have any problems or suggestions, let me know via the comment page on my website.

Comment: Any+Time looks pretty slick. I like it.

Comment: Just implemented AnyTime in a few minutes on a Rails app. Works perfectly.

Comment: I just chose the AnyTime picker as my picker of choice for my JSF app! Thanks for nice product, keep up the good work!

Comment: Any+Time appends a new hidden div for the UI for every Any+Time input (unlike jQUery UI datepicker that reuses the hidden div UI) this makes performance downgrade a lot in the badly designed MSIE6. So do not use Any+Time if you need to support MSIE6!

Comment: Any+Time creates a new widget for each input because each input can have a different format, thereby requiring different buttons. This is the first I've heard of a performance downgrade but I will look into the problem and, if necessary, look for possible solutions that don't break the flexibility of the library.

Comment: Loving this! just implemented this, it's very slick great work :-)

Comment: Looks good, but the license prohibits commercial usage.

Comment: This is looking promising to use for choosing store hours.

Answer (score 14):

In my view, dates and times should be handled as two separate input boxes for it to be most usable and efficient for the user to input. Let the user input one thing at a time is a good principle, imho.

I use the core [UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), and the following time picker.

This one is inspired by the one Google Calendar uses:

**jQuery timePicker**:
examples: http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/
project on github: https://github.com/perifer/timePicker

I found it to be the best among all of the alternatives. User can input fast, it looks clean, is simple, and allows user to input specific times down to the minute.

PS:
In my view: sliders (used by some alternative time pickers) take too many clicks and require mouse precision from the user (which makes input slower).

Comment: Core UI DatePicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: This kills the model binding benefits of C# MVC for that field

Answer (score 13):

My best experience with a datepicker is with the prototype-based [AnyTime](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/).  I know that's not jQuery, but it may still be worth the compromise for you.  I know absolutely no prototype, and it's still easy enough to work with.

One caveat I've found: it is not forward compatible on some browsers.  That is, it did not work with a newer version of prototype on Chrome.

Comment: If I could use prototype this wouldn't be a problem, unfortunately we're stuck with jQuery for this app.

Comment: Just an update - AnyTime 3 now works with jQuery.

Comment: I haven't thought about this for months and months.  But my personal project wanted some updating and I was just about ready to throw in some jquery.  I thought I'd replace the datepicker while I'm at it because I didn't need all the features of Any+Time and thought I might as well go all jQuery.  And bam!  I come across this.  Awesome timing.

Comment: Nice, though the year selector ( clicking < or > ) is kludgy to me.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to the info here, The Fluid Project has a nice wiki write-up overviewing a large number of date and/or time pickers [here](http://wiki.fluidproject.org/display/Infusion13/Date+Time+Picker+Competitive+Analysis).

Answer (score 4):

I researched this just recently and have yet to find a decent date picker that also includes a *decent* time picker. What I ended up using was [eyecon's awesome DatePicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/), with two simple dropdowns for time. I was tempted to use [Timepickr.js](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/) though, looks like a really nice approach.

Answer (score 3):

I have ran into that same problem. I actually developed my using server side programming, but I did a quick search to try and help you out and found this.

Seems alright, didn't look at the source too much, but seems to be purely JavaScript.

Take look:

http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/datetimepicker.htm

Here is the demo page link:

http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/datetimepicker-demo.htm

good luck

Comment: I've been using this for a few years.  It's getting a little long in the tooth but works.

Answer (score 1):

Not jQuery, but it works well for a calendar with time: *[JavaScript Date Time Picker](http://rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/datetimepicker.htm)*.

I just bound the click event to pop it up:

```
$(".arrival-date").click(function() {
    NewCssCal($(this).attr('id'), 'mmddyyyy', 'dropdown', true, 12);
});
```

Comment: Updated the link - they moved it.

Comment: I've been using that one for a few years, though I invoked it differently (hence not recognizing from your code).  I've been migrating to jquery's DatePicker, since the rainforest one is looking a little long in the tooth.

Answer (score 1):

This is some code I use to have a user select one
datetimepicker, set the datetime, and have the
other datetimepicker add One Minute to that time.

I needed this for a custom medication control....

Anyway, thought it might help someone else since I could
not find the answer any where online...

(at least not a complete answer)

Keep in mind that the 60000 added, adds one minute.
(60 * 1000 milliseconds)

```
$('.frdtPicker').datetimepicker({
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            var endDateTextBox = $('.todtPicker');
            if (endDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testStartDate = new Date(dateText);
                var testEndDate = new Date(endDateTextBox.val());
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate) {

                    var testStartDate = new Date(dateText).getTime() + 60000;
                    var testStartDate2 = new Date(testStartDate); 

                    endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('setDate', (new Date(testStartDate2)));
                }
            }
            else {
                var testStartDate = new Date(dateText).getTime() + 60000;
                var testStartDate2 = new Date(testStartDate);
                endDateTextBox.datetimepicker('setDate', (new Date(testStartDate2)));
            }
            $('.frdtPicker').val(dateText); //endDateTextBox.val());

        },
        onSelect: function(selectedDateTime) {
            var start = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
            $('.todtPicker').datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(start.getTime()));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following JavaScript plugin.

[Javascript Calendar with date and time](http://www.jyothis.co.in/2012/05/15/javascript-calendar-with-date-and-time/)

I've made it to be simple as possible. but it still in its early days.
Let me know the feedback so I could improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I make one function like this:

```
function getTime()
{
    var date_obj = new Date();
    var date_obj_hours = date_obj.getHours();
    var date_obj_mins = date_obj.getMinutes();
    var date_obj_second = date_obj.getSeconds();

    var date_obj_time = "'"+date_obj_hours+":"+date_obj_mins+":"+date_obj_second+"'";
    return date_obj_time;
}
```

Then I use the jQuery UI datepicker like this:

```
$("#selector").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd "+getTime()+"" );
```

So, I get the value like this: **2010-10-31 12:41:57**

Comment: sometimes we need to determine the time (not using getTime function)

Answer (score -4):

We had trouble finding one that worked the way we wanted it to so I wrote one. I maintain the source and fix bugs as they arise plus provide free support.

http://www.yart.com.au/Resources/Programming/ASP-NET-JQuery-Date-Time-Control.aspx

Comment: This link is not active unfortunately.