# does jquery date picker allow you to have a picker for date and time

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i have seen some hand rolled solutions but does jquery out of the box support a user picking date and time?

Comment: See this closed duplicate question for others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245245/jquery-date-time-picker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to jQuery UI plugins, I recommend [this timepicker plugin](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/) as one of the better interfaces to selecting the time I've come across.

---

Url updated.

Comment: This link is gone. See this closed duplicate question for others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245245/jquery-date-time-picker

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have anything like that. Do you mean jQuery UI? If so, no.

Answer (score 1):

Well I needed just such a solution so wrote one.
You can find it here, I think it does exactly what you want:

http://www.yart.com.au/Resources/Programming/ASP-NET-JQuery-Date-Time-Control.aspx

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is yes it does

The long answer is jquery itself doesn't, it's the jquery-ui that supports it

Comment: How do you select a time with a datepicker?