# Hours of Day, Days of Week Visual Screen for Web Application

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need a visual frame for my application. There will be hours of day(no need to minutes as like 1:00pm, 1:15pm, 1:30pm, 1:45pm, 2:00pm or something like that, just 1:00pm and 2:00pm is enough) and days of week(no need for weeks of month) And user will be able to select the hours of each day. In my program, it will say that Sunday 1-2 has selected, Monday 9am-1pm and 3pm-6pm have selected or something like that... How can I do that. I searched for JQuery but could find only this: http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/  and this are not for me or I dont can I modify one of them and suitable for my program?

Comment: There's a nice list here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245245/jquery-datetime-picker

Comment: Thanks Andrew. However I should have an ability to select multiple times I mean I will select 2-5 and it means that I have selected 2,3,4 and 5. I should have an ability to select multiple times in a day also I should select multiple times at multiple days of a week.. For example my selection is "Monday 2-4, 7-12 and Sunday 1-3" means that I have selected "Monday 2-3-4, 7-8-9-10-11-12 Sunday 1-2-3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/ this looks like more suitable for me. Just I need to limit its functionality no need to add events just selecting this times?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple list (or div, or option) with [Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) addon for every list item. Timepicker lets yuo to use an hours (and even minutes if you need that).

Comment: Not the thing that what I want.