# datetime_select in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, datetime, sinatra, datetime-select

I've developed a website in Sinatra, but at the last minute I've been told it will need a form with a datetime field (for an Activerecord object). In Rails I would just use the datetime_select helper to construct this field in the view, but I'm having trouble finding a library or extension that provides similar functionality in Sinatra. I could always roll my own, but I'm sure someone has encountered this problem before and probably has a better solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Rails may have a method for this (what *doesn't* it have a method for?) this doesn't seem like a question in the domain of Sinatra. It sounds like you're asking how to create a custom HTML+CSS+JS widget, which is separate from the server-side code.

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, it seems like this question is appropriate:
[jQuery Date/Time Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245245/jquery-date-time-picker)