# Create custom django widget for timefield with now option

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget, django-models

I have models with datetimefields and timefields. When the user interacts with these fields in a form they often just need to enter the current time. I need a now link almost exactly like what shows up in the django admin, so the user can just click it and the current time gets put in the field.

I tried looking through the django source but it seems to utilize some frontend javascript which I'm not very familiar with. Is there a simple way to make a widget that can be easily used in a timefield and datetimefield?

Answer (score 0):

So this is not on the admin panel? As in on the site? Then this is not really a question to be posed to Django, I suggest tagging javascript. If you are unfamiliar with javascript, then tag jquery, they have things for this.

In case you're lazy, here's a start:

[Here](http://keith-wood.name/datetimeEntry.html)

[jQuery premade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245245/jquery-date-time-picker)

[Javascript methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Sorry, but this is more of a UI issue than a Django issue. Hope I helped, though.