# select date time using a pop-up box?

Tags: javascript, prompt

Is there any way to generate a pop-up box that has a drop-down to select date times and after selecting date time clicks on OK button that selected value gets stored in some variable.

I know about **prompt** pop-ups but it only has a **textbox** to take values. How can I set any calendar on onfocus event of that textbox OR how can I set a drop-down for selecting date times instead of textbox.

Thanks

Comment: It is a complicated task to customize prompt box. easier way to do it is to pop up a customized div

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery date/time picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245245/jquery-date-time-picker)

Comment: @Phil I want to do this with pop up. So how to use that jquery ?

Comment: Read the example, its pretty straightforward

Comment: @polin How to customize prompt box at all with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Date Picker]

I hope this is what you want.You can use **Pikaday** plugin.

It is **Lightweight,and has No dependencies**.

**Checkout the Demo**:
http://dbushell.github.com/Pikaday/

**Heres the Complete Documentation:**
https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday