# Show date and time in time picker component in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

Hi I'm working on Struts 2 web project. I am using a jQuery time picker in a web page. But now my client requires to pick the Date and Time to be selected from System clock and calender (Independent of os Windows,Mac,Linux,IOS,etc.). Is there a way to call system clock and calender to pick date and time ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you want a calendar component or just show the current date/time on your site?

Comment: I want to show the calender component on the browser....

Comment: Please add the jQuery or another component you're using as time picker in your site.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm trying that too

Comment: Just post the code by editing your question, somebody will help you to format it.

Comment: You have probably to use javascript or some library to pick up the date and time picker. Calling the system object requires native integration with the clock that it seems not available here.

Answer (score 1):

try [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).. seems, it is what you are looking for..

taken from [jQuery date/time picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245245/jquery-date-time-picker)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of HTML5's date type.  This shows the popup calendar. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score -1):

In javascript

```
new Date()
```

always picks date from the System clock and calendar

Comment: I want to show the calender to the user to pick date and time not getting system date and time values..

Comment: @Ram you mean you want the date and time picker from os

Comment: did u mean that if user clicks on the web page the OS date-time picker should open?