# Looking for a date picker API that can grey out days without events

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, date

**I am looking for a date picking API that has the ability to grey out (or not allow the user to select) certain days.**

I am creating a web page that will display chart data.  The users should be able to select a date to see the graph of data for that day.  If no data exists for a certain day, I need to be able to make it grayed out or not selectable.

Does anyone know of a good date picker API that has this ability?

Comment: this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245245/jquery-date-time-picker?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jquery-ui allows that through Datepicker object :

- http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/